# Event never gets emitted in VueJS within an axios call

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a component which needs to initialize data at the beginning, it does some transformations to the data (based on some values which are saved in localstorage to mark those data as selected).

Using Vue 2.5.

```js
// component.vue

import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    fetchedData: [],
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getStuff()

    window.Bus.$on('localStorageRefreshed', this.getStuff)
  },

  computed: {
    selectedData() {
      return this.fetchedData.filter(data => data.selected)
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getStuff() {
      const doTransformations = function (res, existing) {
        // blabla
      }

      axios.get('/endpoint/for/stuff/').then(result => {
        doTransformations(result, this.fetchedData) // not exactly what happens, but I think this is unneeded to solve my problem. mostly there to illustrate how this all fits together.
        window.Bus.$emit('stuffFetched', this.selectedData)
      })
    },
  }
})
```

So window.Bus is a Vue instance which is just posing as a global event handler. Within my `getStuff`-method, the event never gets emitted, and I have no idea why. I've console logged everywhere in order to figure out if the bus is just not initialized (it is, because I have tons of components which works perfectly with it). The event is just never emitted. I've tried wrapping the emitting in `$nextTick` but that doesn't work either (I also tried doing this directly in the `mounted`-lifecycle method, because the computed property updates in Vue devtools like it should and contains all the right stuff).

I'm really at a loss of what to do here, everything seems to work like it should, but the event is not even registered in Vue devtools.

The reason I need to fire this event is in order to do some price calculations for another component which exists outside of the scope of this child and it's parent. Just emitting in the child scope (`this.$emit('dataChanged')`) doesn't emit an event either using this approach.

Anyone have an idea of what my ******* brain is doing to me here?

Comment: In the line `window.Bus.$emit('stuffFetched', selectedData)`, what is `selectedData`? That doesn't seem to be declared anywhere. Can you confirm that you aren't seeing any console errors? Can you put console logging on the first and last lines of the `then` callback to establish which lines are being reached?

Comment: You use `window.Bus`, this is the hole in the wall. Now you are not sure when and how the bus was initialized. This can cause your issue. Try to change the code to use the bus as the module, like here https://medium.com/easyread/vue-as-event-bus-life-is-happier-7a04fe5231e1. As for me, I prefer to use vuex for this purpose: https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: @skirtle selectedData is supposed to be `this.selectedData` which is a computed property. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AndriyKuba I've made sure that window.Bus is initialized by `console.log`ging it at both the line before I emit the event and after. It is 100% accessible and available, it is instantiated way before anything else in my app. I have no time to refactor to use vuex, but I absolutely would if I could.

Comment: @AndriyKuba I tried to use the event bus as a module, but it still isn't bothering to emit the event from the axios-call.

Comment: So the emit is happening first at the mounted-hook. I found some documentation stating that if you emit something from a child which should be captured in a parent at the mounted-hook, it won't work? Wtf.

Comment: are you sure that `.then(result => {` is firing? I mean are you sure that line `window.Bus.$emit('stuffFetched', this.selectedData)` is accessible?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to just fire it directly in `mounted`. I've tried console logging inside the resolve (`.then`) to verify (it fires, everything works), but no event is being emitted. I tried adding a console log to see which `mounted` is bound first, and the parent seems to be the first to mount, as should be expected. I've tried console.logging this.selectedData, and it contains data. I get no errors in console, but the event is never registered within Vue DevTools either.

Comment: After some advice from a coworker I added a `setTimeout` to my `getStuff`-method. It worked, but it feels very wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use async await? 
That i'll probably make the timeout job, something like:

```
async mounted() {
  await this.getStuff()

  window.Bus.$on('localStorageRefreshed', this.getStuff)
}
```

and then do that on your getStuff too:

```
async getStuff() {
  const doTransformations = function (res, existing) {
    // blabla
  }

  await axios.get('/endpoint/for/stuff/').then(result => {
      doTransformations(result, this.fetchedData) // not exactly what happens, 
           but I think this is unneeded to solve my problem. mostly there to 
           illustrate how this all fits together.
    window.Bus.$emit('stuffFetched', this.selectedData)
  })
}
```

Comment: Haha, I'm glad I helped ;)

Comment: Much sleeker than using the setTimeout-function which I described in one of my comments. Damn, son.